# Android: Phonegap Plugin for playing video in-App

Tags: android, cordova, video

In my phonegap app, I have some videos playing from youtube and some other MP4 (h263) videos in the html.

On iOS, I found a nice plugin for playing these videos natively, in a stable and control-able MPMoviePlayerController instead of this buggy webview  object.

Now on Android, I miss a similar phonegap plugin and could only find one that sends the video URL to the youtube app. I.e. the user leaves the phonegap app when playing the video which is not wanted, of course.

Instead, the android.media.MediaPlayer should handle the playback.

Can you recommend a phonegap plugin for dealing with videos on android?

Thanks for sharing.

Comment: There seems to be one [here](https://github.com/remcob00/cordova-phonegap_youtube_player_api_android)

Comment: Here's one compatible with last phonegap version : https://github.com/macdonst/VideoPlayer

Comment: @Gajotres: Does this plugin play the video inapp? in my test, it redirects to the youtube app :-/

Comment: No, it redirects to the YouTube app. I know this for sure since I wrote it.